# Не отображаются кнопки в HTML проекте

Tags: html, css

Здраствуйте! Столкнулся с проблемой. В HTML не отображаются кнопки[image: Из всех кнопок есть только "Форум"]

Форум это ссылка на форум. А остальные кнопки, которые находятся на рядом это html странички.

```
 <a href="index.html"><div class="MarketplaceNavLogo"><img src="assets/logo.png" alt="Marketplace"></div></a>
    <a href="index.html" class="MarketplaceNavItem">Home</a>
    <a href="Blog.html" class="MarketplaceNavItem">Blog</a>
    <a href="https://marketplace.forum.com/">Forum</a>
    <a href="party-packs.html" class="MarketplaceNavItem">Party Packs</a>
    <a href="safety.html" class="MarketplaceNavItem">Safety</a>
    <a href="faq.html" class="MarketplaceNavItem">FAQ</a>
    <a href="contact.html" class="MarketplaceNavItem">Contact</a>
    <a href=""class="MarketplaceNavItem"><i class='bx bx-search MarketplaceNavItem'></i></a>
    <a href="login.html" class="MarketplaceLoginBtn MarketplaceNavItem">Login</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hambIcon"><i class='bx bx-menu'></i></a>
</div>
<div class="MarketplaceRespMenu">
```

Если я уберу ссылку на форум, все выгялядит как мне нужно, но тогда кнопка "Форум" будет бесполезной...

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Из примера ничего не понятно. 
Используйте инспектор в браузере.

Comment: В вашем коде нет `кнопок`, а есть `ссылки`.